# Conditional For Loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a for loop in python that will generate random numbers (weights) for a specific number of portfolios. However, I want to make sure I have a minimum number of exposure to some tickers. For example I want to make sure that tickers B and C will account for at least 80% of the portfolio. That is I need to have a bunch of random weights generated for the portfolio such that tickers B & C will account for at least 80% of the portfolio.

My code is below, but it doesn't seem to really generate random portfolios with weights > 80%

```
ar = np.array([0,1,1,0])

number_of_portfolios = 5

tickers = ['A','B','C','D'] 

portfolio_weights = []


for portfolio in range (number_of_portfolios):
   weights = np.random.random_sample(len(tickers))
    weights = np.round((weights / np.sum(weights)),3)
    if sum(ar * weights) > 0.8:
        portfolio_weights.append(weights)
```

Thank you!

I was expecting to get 5 differently weighted portfolios with tickers C and C accounting for at least 80% of the portfolio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a little issue with your code which is it belive that it yeild output every time. but it actually won't.

to be more precise the probability of getting 0.8 or more for 2 variables is severely biased with very less probability. so you can repeatedly call the guess random to obtain the output. i believe it takes on average 70-92 guesses, on worst case it can go upto 130+ tries.

hope my explaination is clear.

try this code:

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([0,1,1,0])
number_of_portfolios = 5

tickers = ['A','B','C','D'] 

portfolio_weights = []
found=0
count=0
while count<5:
    weights = np.random.random_sample(len(tickers))
    weights = np.round(weights / np.sum(weights),3)
    if sum(ar * weights) > 0.8:
        portfolio_weights.append(weights)
        count+=1
print("obtained output is :",portfolio_weights)
```

if you are interested on knowing how many tries it takes on average run this to see the number of tries.

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([0,1,1,0])
number_of_portfolios = 5

tickers = ['A','B','C','D'] 

portfolio_weights = []
found=0
count=0
tries=0

while count<5:
    weights = np.random.random_sample(len(tickers))
    weights = np.round(weights / np.sum(weights),3)
    tries+=1
    if sum(ar * weights) > 0.8:
        portfolio_weights.append(weights)
        count+=1
print("obtained output is :",portfolio_weights)
print("number of tries it took to yeild result :",tries)
```

if this helps leaving a upvote is appreciated.